# Weird reason make my images won't show

Tags: html, css, image

I am a beginer but I already made websites so, I know HTML, CSS, and working with servers and FTP.
I was working on my html, and some weiiiird thing happenned to me (for me, as I really don't understand what is happening, it is weird...)

So, Localy, my images in the section "projets" shows, as asked by the code.
BUT, on my server, the images won't show. They are IDENTICAL lines, the images ares correctly named (01.jpg.02.jpg...) and placed on the server, the images 1 and 4 shows correctly, but the others, nope. I tried to copy/past the line from picture 1 to the picture 2 line and, the site shows picture 1 two times, so, I really don't understand at all what is wrong...

my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Web Agency</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

    <header style="background-color: #fafafa"> <!-- entête du site, contiendra le menu de navigation ainsi que le carrousel-->
        <nav class="nav" role="navigation"> <!-- navigation-->
            <a href="#"><img src="./webagency_images/images/logo.png" /></a>
            <ul clas="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="slider"> <!-- carrousel-->
            <figure>
                <img src="./webagency_images/images/slider/bg1.jpg" alt="Images Slider">
                <img src="./webagency_images/images/slider/bg2.jpg" alt="Images Slider">
            </figure>
            <figcaption><h1><span style="color:#62a8d0">WEBAGENCY</span> : L'AGENCE DE TOUS VOS PROJETS!</h1><p>Vous avez un projet Web? La WebAgency vous aide à le réaliser!</p><br/><br/>
                <button class="button" type="button"><a href="#">Plus D'infos</a></button>
            </figcaption>
        </div>
        <!-- navigation dans le carrousel-->
        <div class="slider_navigation">
            <div class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></div>
            <div class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- section services de la page du site-->
    <section class="services">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">NOS SERVICES</h1>
        <div class="point_bleu"></div>
        <hr/>
        <p class="bloc_centre">Nous proposons les meilleurs services et en plus, aux meilleurs prix!! Nous avons une équipe de professionnels tous prêt à accueillir votre projet et lui donner vie selon vos souhaits. N'hésitez pas à nous contacter pour un devis, un projet web ou pour un magasin web. Les éléments pris en charge par l'UX vont de la partie commerciale à l'accessibilité.</p><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="assides">
        <img src="./webagency_images/images/main-feature.png" />
        <div class="blocs"><h1>UX Design</h1>
            <p><b>U</b>ser e<b>X</b>périence : son rôle à pour but de faire la liaison entre l'interface construite, et l'utilisateur. Il est chargé de rendre l’expérience d'utilisation fluide, simple, intuitive, de faciliter l'utilisation de l'utilisateur, de réfléchir pour lui à tout ces moyens là d'avoir la meilleure expérience possible sur son support.</p>

            <div class=""><h1>UI Design</h1>
                <p><b>U</b>ser <b>I</b>nterface : son rôle est là pour rendre accessible, optimale et facile, l'accès et l’exécution des dispositifs liés à l'interface des applications et machines.</p>
            </div>
            <div class=""><h1>SEO</h1>
                <p><b>S</b>earch <b>E</b>ngine <b>O</b>ptimization : son rôle est d'optimiser au mieux le référencement des outils web, d'un site... Le travaille se fait sur les mots clés, la sémantique, l'étude de la concurrence, du marché actuel et doit être fait régulièrement pour mettre à jour les données importantes au référencement.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- section portfolio de la page du site -->
    <section class="projets">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">NOS PROJETS</h1>
        <div class="point_bleu"></div>
        <hr/>
        <p class="bloc_centre">Lorem Ipsum et tout le tralala blablabla à remplir plus tard.</p><br />
        <div class="row">
            <div><img src="./webagency_images/images/portfolio/01.jpg" alt="Image1"/></div>
            <div><img src="./webagency_images/images/portfolio/02.jpg" alt="Image2"/></div>
            <div><img src="./webagency_images/images/portfolio/03.jpg" alt="Image3"/></div>
            <div><img src="./webagency_images/images/portfolio/04.jpg" alt="Image4"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div><img src="./webagency_images/images/portfolio/05.jpg" alt="Image5"/></div>
            <div><img src="./webagency_images/images/portfolio/06.jpg" alt="Image6"/></div>
            <div><img src="./webagency_images/images/portfolio/07.jpg" alt="Image7"/></div>
            <div><img src="./webagency_images/images/portfolio/08.jpg" alt="Image8"/></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- bas de page contenant un iframe google maps et un formulaire de contact-->
    <footer>
        <form method="post">
            <div>
                <h1>Contact Info</h1>
                <h4>WebAgency SAS<br /> 25 rue d'Hauteville 75010 Paris<br /> Tel : 01 02 03 04 05</h4>
            </div>
            <label for="Nom"></label>
            <input type="text" name="Nom" placeholder="Nom"><br/>
            <label for="E-mail"></label>
            <input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail"><br />
            <label for="Sujet"></label>
            <input type="text" name="Sujet" placeholder="Sujet"><br />
            <label for="Message"></label>
            <textarea type="text" rows="10" cols="35" placeholder="Votre message"></textarea><br />
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Envoyer" style="width: 50%">
        </form>

        <div class="google_iframe">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d11139.440186098542!2d4.878186999999999!3d45.73390145!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sfr!4v1524499866273" width="100%" height="650" frameborder="0" style="border:0; opacity: 0.7" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </footer>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The link to my website page :

http://web-tool-box.com//openclassrooms/projets/webagency/webagency.html#

Am I making some "stupid junior mistake"?

Comment: Either the images don't exist where you think they do, or maybe something went wrong with the transfer/setting permissions: `http://web-tool-box.com//openclassrooms/projets/webagency/webagency_images/images/portfolio/02.jpg` returns a 403. Try deleting all the images from that folder and re-uploading them.

Comment: It seems like your images 02.jpg, 03.jpg, 05.jpg, 07.jpg 08.jpg don't seem to be uploaded into your server. Try uploading them again.

Comment: Check if your image uploads were successful cause `http://web-tool-box.com/openclassrooms/projets/webagency/webagency_images/images/portfolio/02.jpg` `03.jpg` and so on is not accessible.

Comment: Okay, in fact, the problem was about permissions. The links were good, and the images was already in the right place and all. New problem I never had before, I learned something, thanks to you guys =)